# Solve: Use a function from the child component to assign a value into the props?

Tags: reactjs

In my parent component, there's a state that stores the selected task id from the child component. I used the props to pass the data from child to parent component. But my problem is I will use a function that will generate the selected task id inside the child component. The result that i want is if the user selects a button it will trigger the function that will generate the task id. Then it will store the data into props that will be pass to the parent component. The reason why the i will used a function instead of using onClick={e => e.currentTarget.getAttribute('taskkd')} I will also need to pass other props that will display the dialog box.

**Parent Component**

```
const Home = () => {
  let userInfo = localStorage.getItem('userData');
  const [taskDeleteId, setTaskDeleteId] = useState();
  const [showPrompt, setShowPrompt] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(taskDeleteId);
  }, [history, taskDeleteId]);

  return (
    <>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={8} className={baseClasses.mainTaskContainer}>
          <TasksList
            deleteId={(deleteId) => setTaskDeleteId(deleteId)}
            showPrompt={(showPrompt) => setShowPrompt(showPrompt)}
          />
          <PromptComponent showPrompt={showPrompt} shownewArr={newArr} />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </>
  );
};
```

**Child Component**

```
const TasksList = ({ deleteId, showPrompt }) => {
  const selectedTask = (e) => {
    deleteId = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('taskid'); <--- the task id that i need to pass into my parent component
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Container
        component='div'
        maxWidth='xl'
        className={classes.taskContainer}
      ><Container
        component='div'
        maxWidth='xl'
        className={classes.taskContainer}
      >
        <Container
          component='div'
          maxWidth='xl'
          className={classes.todoContainer}
          onDragOver={(e) => onDragOverTask(e)}
          onDragLeave={(e) => onDragLeaveTask(e)}
          onDrop={(e) => onDropTask(e)}
        >
          <Typography variant='h6' className={classes.containerTitle}>
            <span>To do</span>
            <span>{taskTodo.length}</span>
          </Typography>
          {taskTodo.map((currentTask, index) => {
            return (
              <Card
                variant='outlined'
                className={classes.cardTask}
                key={index}
                style={{ background: '#f3f3f3', marginTop: '1rem' }}
                onDragStart={(e) => onDragStartTask(e, currentTask._id)} 
                draggable
              >
                {currentTask.desc && (
                  <Collapse
                    in={expanded === `todo-panel_${index}`}
                    timeout='auto'
                    unmountOnExit
                    className={classes.collapsePanel}
                    color='primary'
                  >
                    <CardContent className={classes.descPrevContainer}>
                      <Typography
                        variant='body1'
                        className={classes.text}
                        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup(
                          textTruncate(currentTask.desc, 50)
                        )}
                      ></Typography>
                    </CardContent>
                  </Collapse>
                )}
                <CardActions
                  disableSpacing
                  className={classes.bottomActionsContainer}
                >
                  <Tooltip title='Delete'>
                    <IconButton
                      aria-label='delete'
                      className={classes.BottomDelete}
                      taskid={currentTask._id}
                      onClick={(() => showPrompt(true), selectedTask)} <--- props
                    >
                      <DeleteIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                  </Tooltip>
                  <Tooltip title='Edit'>
                    <IconButton
                      aria-label='edit'
                      className={classes.BottomEdit}
                      taskid={currentTask._id}
                    >
                      <EditIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                  </Tooltip>
                </CardActions>
              </Card>
            );
          })}
        </Container>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Can you describe it more? Not able to understand your actual problem.

Comment: Sir, I made a simple mistake, but it's already fine now